# Using group_by() to identify highest priority for a given item

Tags: python, group-by, sqlalchemy

I have the following table that I am reading using SQLAlchemy in Python

[image]

I need to group by the "id" and return a column called priority which will have the following conditions:

- if "high" exist in values then "high"
- else if "medium" exist in values then "medium"
- else if "low" exist in values then "low"
- else "no priority found"

to have the following output:

[image]

what should be the SQLAlchemy syntax to have this group by operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to map the "priority" values in the main table

```
"task_list"

id  priority
--  --------
 1  low     
 1  medium  
 2  high    
 2  medium  
 3  low     
 3  no      
 4  no      
 4  no
```

with numeric values that will behave correctly when we `min()` them. We can to that with a lookup table

```
"priority"

key     priority_value  description      
------  --------------  -----------------
high                 1  high             
medium               2  medium           
low                  3  low              
no                   4  no priority found
```

so we can then use code like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

# …

with engine.begin() as conn:
    map_to_priority_values = (
        sa.select(task_list.c.id, priority.c.priority_value)
        .select_from(
            sa.join(
                task_list, priority, task_list.c.priority == priority.c.key
            )
        )
        .subquery()
    )

    min_priority_value_by_id = (
        sa.select(
            map_to_priority_values.c.id,
            sa.func.min(map_to_priority_values.c.priority_value).label(
                "min_value"
            ),
        )
        .group_by(map_to_priority_values.c.id)
        .subquery()
    )

    map_to_priority_descriptions = (
        sa.select(min_priority_value_by_id.c.id, priority.c.description)
        .select_from(
            sa.join(
                min_priority_value_by_id,
                priority,
                min_priority_value_by_id.c.min_value
                == priority.c.priority_value,
            )
        )
        .order_by(min_priority_value_by_id.c.id)
    )

    results = conn.execute(map_to_priority_descriptions).all()
    print(results)
    # [(1, 'medium'), (2, 'high'), (3, 'low'), (4, 'no priority found')]
```